# Multi-Class CNN model predicting only one class but still the accuracy is high

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, transfer-learning

Before marking the question as repeated, note that I have read most of them but did not find the solution. I have given all the information on model below so please give advice for it.

I am working on Facial Sentiment Analysis. I am using transfer learning with ResNet50 to train a dataset of 28k RGB images. The model is giving validation accuracy of 83.33% (which is constant for all epochs) and predicting only one label.

**"The problem here is that the label3 (i.e. Neutral label) it is predicting has 31.8% proportion in the data and still the accuracy comes out to be 83.33%."**

The code and confusion matrix is below. Am I using the *model.predict_generator* incorrectly?
Please note that I passed my *test_set* in the *predict_generator*.

**Data Distribution:**

Test:  (Anger-646), (Disgust-970), (Happiness-1927), (Neutral-2232), (Sadness-836), (Surprise-399)

Training:  (Anger-1935), (Disgust-2908), (Happiness-5778), (Neutral-6693), (Sadness-2505), (Surprise-1195)

**Model:**

```
    Rsnt_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(64, 64, 3))

    for layer in Rsnt_model.layers:
        layer.trainable=False


    #av1 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(Rsnt_model.output)
    av1=layers.Flatten()(Rsnt_model.output)
    fc1 = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))(av1)
    drp1=Dropout(0.35)(fc1)
    fc2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(drp1)
    drp2=Dropout(0.2)(fc2)
    bat_norm=layers.BatchNormalization()(fc2)
    fc3 = Dense(68, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))(bat_norm)
    #drp3=Dropout(0.25)(fc3)
    fc4 = Dense(34, activation='relu')(fc3)
    out = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(fc4)
    tl_model = Model(inputs=Rsnt_model.input,outputs=out)

tl_model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I am using BinaryCrossEntropy because of multi-label classification

**training_test_set code**

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train_test_dataset/Train',
        target_size=(64, 64),    
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical',
        )

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train_test_dataset/Test',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical',
        )
```

**Epochs**

```
Epoch 1/10
335/335 [==============================] - 123s 368ms/step - loss: 1.0045 - accuracy: 0.8329 - val_loss: 0.5025 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 2/10
335/335 [==============================] - 113s 338ms/step - loss: 0.4883 - accuracy: 0.8330 - val_loss: 0.5093 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 3/10
335/335 [==============================] - 117s 350ms/step - loss: 0.4926 - accuracy: 0.8329 - val_loss: 0.4996 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 4/10
335/335 [==============================] - 113s 338ms/step - loss: 0.4909 - accuracy: 0.8332 - val_loss: 0.4978 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 5/10
335/335 [==============================] - 113s 336ms/step - loss: 0.4898 - accuracy: 0.8334 - val_loss: 0.4975 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
```

**Code for *predict_generator*, *evaluate_generator* and *confusion matrix***

```
preds=tl_model.predict_generator(
    test_set
    )    
evals=tl_model.evaluate_generator(
    test_set
    )    
import numpy as np
pred=[]
for i in preds:
   pred.append(np.argmax(i))

lbls=test_set.labels    

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_mat=confusion_matrix(lbls, pred)
```

---

```
print(preds)
[[0.07126013 0.16465071 0.23472613 0.39474297 0.08812989 0.04649016]
 [0.07160447 0.16465573 0.23501842 0.39354676 0.08840203 0.04677264]
 [0.07140011 0.16469218 0.2348036  0.39425436 0.08823967 0.0466101 ]
 ...
 [0.0716239  0.16465151 0.23494086 0.3935586  0.08842354 0.04680166]
 [0.07143697 0.16465022 0.23501226 0.3940167  0.08823942 0.04664437]
 [0.07193935 0.16459921 0.23527609 0.39246148 0.08866104 0.04706287]]
```

---

```
print(evals)
[0.49759348820556293, 0.83333373]
```

---

```
print(conf_mat)
[[   0    0    0  646    0    0]
 [   0    0    0  970    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 1927    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 2232    0    0]
 [   0    0    0  836    0    0]
 [   0    0    0  399    0    0]]
```

Comment: One thing I notice: You are using `loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` which only works if there are two labels but you are predicting multiple labels. I think you should use `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`

Comment: I have used CategoricalCrossEntropy but the accuracy was around ~35%. I also read somewhere that for multi-label problems, BinaryCrossEntropy is a better choice since all the labels are not exclusive i.e. one image can belong to multiple labels.

Comment: I am a bit confused: Quoting from the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy): „Use this cross-entropy loss when there are only two label classes (assumed to be 0 and 1).“
I suppose (but am not sure about this) that tensorflow will in some way binarize your labels when using binary crossentropy which will skew your accuracy and loss. This also seems to be confirmed by the fact that only one column of the confusion matrix is non-zero (so only one class is predicted??).

Comment: Hi, sorry for such a late reply Maximilian. Yes, you are right. It is only predicting one class and this can be seen from confusion matrix. But the strangest thing happening here is that the class that is always predicted has 31.8% proportion in whole dataset. But the accuracy is 83.33%.
You can see that this is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: So, what happens if you use CategoricalCrossentropy ? :D